# Navigation from action react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

The structure of my files is something like that

```
 - actions directory
    - user.js
 - navigation directory
    - tabNavigator.js

 - screens directory
    - Home.js
    - Login.js
    - Account.js
```

In **user.js** in **actions directory** I have a function that make possible the authentification process,for thet I am in **Login.js** if the authentification is available I want to navigate to **Account.js**

Here is the code:

**user.js**

```
export const loginIntoAccount = ()=>{
return async (dispatch,getState) =>{
    try{
        const {email, password} = getState().user;
        //Login Api
        const data = new FormData();
            data.append('email', email);
            data.append('password', password);

        let configUserLogin = {
            method:'post',
            url:apiConfig.logInUser,
            headers: { 
                credentials: true,
                exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"],
                'Cookie': ['set-cookie'], 
            },
            data : data
        }
        
        axios(configUserLogin).then((response) =>{
           
            if(response.status == 200){
                dispatch({type:"GET_USER_LOGGED_DATA",payload:response.data})
            }else{
                alert('Adresa de email sau parola gresite!')
            }
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            //  alert('ss' + error);
        }).finally(function () {
            console.log('Finally called');
     
        });  

    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
  }
}
```

If everything is ok the code works I get user data from DB.
But the problem is the following if the authentication is ok I want to navigate to **Account.js**

I tried something like that:

1. I import a react native module

   ```
       import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
   ```
2. And then in the condition below I put the following code:

   ```
      if( response.status == 200){
                dispatch({type:"GET_USER_LOGGED_DATA",payload:response.data})


                const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
                    routeName: "Account",
                    params: {},
                    action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Account" })
                  });
                this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);

            }else{
                alert('Adresa de email sau parola gresite!')
            }
   ```

But it does not work

3)I try another way after an exemple find on this page:
[exemple code](https://medium.com/@dariaruckaolszaska/navigate-from-your-redux-actions-with-react-navigation-in-your-react-native-app-d3bf1fbd4c08)

```
return async (dispatch,getState,navigation) =>{
     .......
     if(status == 200)
       navigation.navigate('Account)
}
```

4. Fallow another exemple on internet I try somenthing like that: [another exemple](https://medium.com/@dariaruckaolszaska/navigate-from-your-redux-actions-with-react-navigation-in-your-react-native-app-d3bf1fbd4c08)

```
return async (dispatch,getState) =>{
     .......
     if(status == 200)
       dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Account' });
}
```

What I want to get is when I log in and everything is fine to redirect me to the screen from my account.

Answer (score 1):

Create a stack navigator in the root of you application like

```
<Stack.Navigator
         
        >
          
          {authToken === '' ? (
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Auth"
              component={AuthStack}
           
            />
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Main"
              component={MainNavigator}
              
            />
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
```

Where AuthStack is the stack that contains the login screen/ sign up screen etc and MainNavigator contains all the screens which you want to show on after the user has logged in.
Your authToken can come from you store management system or asyncstorage.
Based on the condition react-navigation will automatically handle navigation for you so you don't have to navigate manually after authtoken has a value.
Refer: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/